# jquery show/hide field

Tags: jquery, animation, textfield

I am having problems with getting my text field to hide/show properly. here is the example:

[JFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vsYB8/16/)

What I want is for the text field to only show when the selected value is equal to one and to be hidden for everything else. The checkbox portion is working properly.

Code copied from jsfiddle:

```
<html>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Test Page</title>
<body>
  <table id="testList">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox'></td>

        <td><select>
   <option value="0">Volvo</option>
   <option value="1">Saab</option>
   <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="3">Audi</option><input type='text' style="display: none">
            </select>
</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
<td><select>
   <option value="0">Volvo</option>
   <option value="1">Saab</option>
   <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="3">Audi</option>
 </select><input type='text' style="display: none">
      </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
<td><select>
   <option value="0">Volvo</option>
   <option value="1">Saab</option>
   <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="3">Audi</option>
    </select> <input type='text' style="display: none">
</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {


      $("select").change(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $checkbox = $this.parent().prev().find(":checkbox");

        if ($this.val() != 0) {
        $checkbox.attr("disabled", true);
            if($this.val() == 1){
            $(":text").show();
            }
            else{
                $(":text").hide();
            }    


        } else {
          $checkbox.removeAttr("disabled");
        }

          });

      $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $select = $this.parent().next().find("select");

        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
          $select.attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
          $select.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
      });

    });
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/vsYB8/20/

Instead of using `$(':text').show()` you need `$(this).siblings(':text').show()`.

This will select the corresponding text box and not all of them.

Comment: how do you get the text field to also hide when the value is = 0?